# OAuth2, creating local accounts using Facebook and Google

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm currently trying to implement OAuth2-based registration/login to a project that I'm working on.

A thought struck me; if a user decides to login to the site the first time using Facebook and the second time using Google;

1) Is it possible to connect the two different login methods to the same account?

2) Is it a good idea?

At first I thought I could use the email as a unique identifier, but I doubt that is secure enough.

Is there a way to accomplish this, or should you simply create two separate accounts for the two, depending on which login method they used?

Answer (score 0):

why should the e-mail as unique identifier lack security?
The only problem could be that a user is having kind of spam mail address at facebook to avoid those email notifications. But you could give the user a cookie and if he's trying to authenticate a second time with google instead of facebook, from were he created his account you can work around a function that is enabling him to connect the google subaccount to the main one, created with facebook. But this needs quite a amount of time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has a page for guidance on this issue. It's quite comprehensive with respect to security issues and best practices:

> If you use an email address as the unique credential which identifies each account, your app should verify that the email address associated with the person's Facebook account (and obtained during Facebook Login) is valid. You can do this by creating code in your app to send a verification email to the address obtained after Facebook Login (you will probably need to have this step as part of your regular login system anyway).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers

Whether or not you deem this necessary will depend upon what your website does or allows via a login.

Comment: I've been doing this for years already with PayPal - I figured if someone can log into their PayPal account they could have just created a new account with us anyway so I let it auto-login. Never had an issue with this.